# Download pdf from a URL instead of opening in a new tab

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular10

Is there any possible way in Angular 10 / Typescript to download a PDF from a URL instead of opening it in a new tab?

Sample URL: http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to download and save it an anchor tag with the download attribute as @sasa suggests should suffice. Here's some sample code for Angular.

```html
<a [href]="url" download>Click to download</a>
```

If you'd like to programatically download the file you need to use the `HttpClient` from Angular:

Install this dependency to make your life easier:

```sh
npm install file-saver --save
npm install -D @types/file-saver
```

And have a generic service

```js
import {saveAs} from 'file-saver'
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DownloadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  downloadUrl(url: string, filename: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob' }).pipe(
      map(res => res.blob()),
      tap(blob => saveAs(blob, filename))
    )
  }
}
```

**Notice that calling the function won't download the file; you will need to `subscribe` to the `Observable<Blob>` returned or transform it into a `Promise` and await it**

Comment: <a [href]="url" download>Click to download</a> This is taking to the new tab

Comment: You may use the service I provided you with. That pops up a dialog to save the file

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the content type as application/octet-stream typically to inform the browser that it should download it instead of displaying it in a tab.  Not sure specifically how in Angular 10 / Typescript:

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm being too obvious but the `download` attribute to the `a` tag doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to download file using code.